# tikz array of coordinates: iteration and addressing elements

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Given the following array of coordinates

```
 \def\points{ (-1, 3) (2, 7) (3, 8) }
```

(see its use e.g. in [TikZ: Smooth curve through three points without changing direction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309388/tikz-smooth-curve-through-three-points-without-changing-direction))

how do I

1. iterate (in `tikz`) over the coordinates?
   e.g.

   ```
   "iterate over coordinates"
         {
   How to get the coordinate the iterator is pointing to?
   How to get the iteration index?
         }
   ```
2. address an element directly, e.g. coordinate 2 (i.e. (2, 7))
   e.g.

   ```
   \coordinate (A) at ("second coordinate at \points");
   ```

A similar question regarding 2D matrices in `tikz` is posed at [2D tikz matrices: iteration and addressing elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404130/2d-tikz-matrices-iteration-and-addressing-elements)

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example people can compile. What is the problem iterating over the coordinates? This usually works out-of-the-box, so it isn't clear what the problem might be as you don't say. You can retrieve the x/y part using the lower level PGF stuff. There's a question about this somewhere.

Comment: I'd probably use `\foreach \x/\y in {-1/3, 2/7, 3/8} {...}` but, as cfr says, without a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) it's tricky to say whether this is the best approach for you.

Comment: expanded my questions

Comment: I think you have been asking XY questions where you want X but asking about Y's. How do you want to use these points?

Comment: No, I need the answers exactly as specified. Anything else (such as their use) is not important.

Comment: Note that if you want to reply to a specific user, you should write an at-sign followed by the username, e.g. @percusse, otherwise the user wont be notified of your comment (you as the owner of the post is always notified). You can only ping one user per comment though.

Comment: @Viesturs Then your question is answered in your previous questions. Just make an array and access them as specified by egreg's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first one, there is a simple solution.  The second one is not so easy.  You just have to iterate and print when you hit the index.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\points{(-1,3), (2,7), (3,8)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \p in \points {
    \node at \p {\p};
  }

  \foreach \p [count=\i] in \points {
    \ifnum\i=2
      \node at \p {Hello};
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```